# sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve: Why are the precision and recall returned arrays instead of single values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I am calculating the precisions and recall for off-the-shelf algorithms on a dataset that I recently prepared.

It is a binary classification problem and I am looking to calculate the precision, recall and the f-scores for each of the classifier I built.

```
test_x, test_y, predics, pred_prob,score = CH.buildBinClassifier(data,allAttribs,0.3,50,'logistic')
```

The build classifier method basically builds a classifier, fits a training data and returns test_x(the features of the test data), test_y(the ground truth labels), predict(predictions made by the classifier), red_prob(prediction probabilities from the `LogisiticRegression.predict_proba` method).

Below is the code for calculating precision-recall:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve

pr, re, _ = precision_recall_curve(test_y,pred_prob,pos_label=1)
pr
(array([ 0.49852507,  0.49704142,  0.49554896,  0.49702381,  0.49850746,
         0.5       ,  0.5015015 ,  0.50301205,  0.50453172,  0.50606061,
         . . . . . . . 
         0.875     ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,
         1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ])
re
array([ 1.        ,  0.99408284,  0.98816568,  0.98816568,  0.98816568,
         0.98816568,  0.98816568,  0.98816568,  0.98816568,  0.98816568,
         . . . . . . . 
         0.04142012,  0.04142012,  0.03550296,  0.0295858 ,  0.02366864,
         0.01775148,  0.01183432,  0.00591716,  0.        ]))
```

I do not understand why are precision and recall arrays? Shouldn't they be just single numbers?

Since precision is calculated as `tpf/(tpf+fpf)` and similarly recall as definition?

I am aware about calculating the average precision-recall by the following piece of code, but somehow seeing arrays instead of tpf, fpf, precision and recall is making me wonder what is going on.

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as prf

precision,recall,fscore,_ = prf(test_y,predics,pos_label=1,average='binary')
```

Edit:
But without the `average` and `pos_label` parameter it reports the precisions for each of the class. Could someone explain the difference between the outputs of these two methods?

Comment: you asked for precision_recal_**curve**, and a curve is a sequence of points. If you want single values (actual precision and recall) - call **precision** and **recall** functions. Curve is used to visualize dependency on the threshold parameter.

Comment: Thank you. But could you clarify the relevance of these values? Do they correspond to each individual prediction?

Comment: They correspond to different decision thresholds.

Comment: Thank you @BrenBarn. I am wondering if you could point me to the right direction of what different thresholds mean? A way in which I can relate the numbers I see to the data or the decision.

Comment: See for instance [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic).  The curve plotted there is not the precision-recall curve but the concept is similar.  Basically, when deciding which category an item falls into, the model creates some sort of "likelihood score" that represents how likely it is to be in category B.  To make the binary decision, you set some threshold value and label that all items above that threshold as B.  By setting a high threshold you can avoid false positives at the cost of increased false negatives, and so on.

Comment: That helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From the sklearn documentation for precision_recall_curve:

> Compute precision-recall pairs for different probability thresholds.

Classifier models like logistic regression do not actually output class labels (like "0" or "1"), they output *probabilities* (like 0.67). These probabilities tell you the likelihood that the input sample is of a particular class, like the positive ("1") class. But you still need to *choose* a probability threshold so that the algorithm can convert the probability (0.67) into a class ("1").

If you choose a threshold of 0.5, then all input samples with calculated probabilities greater than 0.5 will be assigned to the positive class. If you choose a different threshold and you get a different number of samples assigned to the positive and negative class, and therefore different precision and recall scores.

Comment: This answer was very helpful to my understanding. My only followup question is why scikit's precision_recall_curve function returns, but does not accept the weights.

In your answer, you implied that the analyst gets to choose the threshold.

Reference: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html

Answer (score 1):

In a binary classification problem, pred_prob is the probability of the instance being in each of the classes, so actually the predicted value (classes) depends on this probability and one more value called threshold. All instances with pred_prob bigger than the threshold is classified into one class, and smaller into the other. The default threshold is 0.5.

So, varying the threshold we have different prediction results.  In many problems a much better result may be obtained by adjusting the threshold. That's what gives you the precision_recall_curve.

Comment: what is the range of threshold that we can adjust within? Is it [0, 1]?